# Running Instagram on AVD

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device, instagram

I wanted to use Instagram on my computer, so I decided to use an Android Virtual Device for that task.

I *downloaded the Android SDK and the newest apk for instagram* for my computer.

Then I created a new AVD and ran it. After it was booted, I installed the instagram apk using ***`adb install instagram.apk`***.

*It installed smoothly and after clicking the app, it started*.

**Now here's my problem**: From there on nothing works.

When I try to login and I press the login button, nothing happens like there would be no internet connection.

Browsers and other apps using an internet connection work just fine, just instagram doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you explain your answer in detail please?How were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it has something to do that the android Emulator can't really handle a global proxy.
Therefore hostnames get resolved directly to their IP which violates HTTP 1.1 standarts and the request doesn't get send properly.
To fix this, it is needed to change it so the hostname gets send instead of the IP.

Comment: could you put more detail on your own accepted answer?

Comment: @maddo7 how did you send hostnames instead of IP in the android emulator?
Can you please explain more?

Comment: How do you make it send the hostname?

Answer (score 2):

You should try creating an AVD with different settings. More RAM and allowing GPU emulation is a good idea. If you insist on using an AVD and you have an appropriate intel CPU then you can make the emulator run much faster by following [these steps](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture). They are a bit complicated, but worth it if you want the emulator to run quicker.

I typically try to avoid using the Android emulator while I am developing apps. It has its uses, but it tends to be slow and doesn't have all of the capabilities of actual devices.

As an alternative to using an AVD, I would recommend downloading and installing [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/). BluesStacks was written from the ground up to allow running Android apps on your Windows PC or Mac. I have used it before and it does a great job. Much better than an AVD.

Comment: I recently tried to run Instagram under BlueStacks, and it was very unstable.  I eventually gave up, because I could not successfully post even one single image.  BlueStacks does not seem like stable software.

Comment: I've seen some people using [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) instead of AVDs and it seems like a capable alternative. I gave it a test run and it was pretty smooth.

Answer (score 2):

Try [visual studio emulator for android](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx). Instagram works on it with enabled and connected wifi. This emulator works better than BlueStacks.